# Admin access when forms authentication on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I'm fairly new to Sharepoint, i'm catching up fast (reading + experimenting) but i can't seem to get around this....
I have a web application with its respective site collection and sites, i have anonymous access allowed for all the sites with forms authentication. 
Everything is working fine but i don't know how to login with the administrator account from the internet. With Windows auth you have the "login" link and you just have to use your admin credentials, how can i do that with forms auth??

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable forms authentication as well in your web config file and use membership and role provider db for forms authentication users.

For details please go through the responses for a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039639/how-do-i-pass-login-id-as-parameter-to-sharepoint-login-page) I have asked in the past on stackoverflow.com

Comment: yes, i already did that. But my specific question would be... the admin user is identified just by name? because in windows auth i understand that a user is admin because it is an admin in the domain

Comment: ok, now solved. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/352e9e41-a57f-41e8-af78-70ac4cff8a46?prof=required
thanks for your help =)